# Sort Logfile for unqiue SRC + DST IPs

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I would like to sort my Logfile (~5 GB) for unique connection events.
Unique (SRC_IP + DST_IP) only - but with timestamps and the other informations.

---

**Example:**

```
1    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
2    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.1" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
3    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.1"...
4    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
5    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
```

The output events should be:

```
1    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
2    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.1" dstip="10.10.10.2"...
3    Feb 5 14:59:00 initf="eth0" outift="eth1" srcip="192.168.0.2" dstip="10.10.10.1"...
```

because the combination of src + dst IP is unique. I tried this with sort -uk *column* but it doesn't work as intended. Also the column of src + dst IP are not consistent. It switches sometimes, because depending on the out-interface, the dstmac is submitted or not.

Maybe an AWK script could do the trick ?

**EDIT**

Since Karakfa made a good suggestion, solving this with awk  -  I am currently trying to change [$7,$8] into a regex

```
awk '!a[regexpression for src ip, regexpression for dst ip]++' file
```

- so it won't matter if the position of dst and src IP changes. @Ed Morton

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output plus what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming no spaces in the first 8 field values, this will give you the first appearance of the combination of the key.

```
$ awk '!a[$7,$8]++' file
```

This doesn't require sorted input (and won't change the order itself), you can pipe this into sort with your desired order.
If the field order is not fixed, you can do something like this:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^srcip=/) s=$i; else if($i~/^dstip=/) d=$i}
       !a[s,d]++;
       {s=d=""}' file
```

Note that records with missing fields will be grouped as well.  You may want to print all of those individually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the src and dst IP isn't always in the same row. Can I use a regex instead ? awk '!a["srcip=\S+","dstip=\S+"]++' file  ... something like that ?

Comment: if they are not in the same *row* it's a bigger problem.  How do you correlate them then?  Perhaps you meant *column*?

Comment: yes, my bad  -  they change position sometimes. . but every event contains a src and dst ip

Comment: There is a missing semicolon before "else if" I think. Also I don't know what {s=d=""} is doing - but its working like a charm, thank you :)